# How to make OpenSearch Dashboard allow self-signed certs for OpenID Connect URLs?

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

The problem is that the OpenID Connect URL I'm trying to reach uses self-signed certs. The plugin `securityDashboards` doesn't seem to like that:

`Error: unable to verify the first certificate\ n at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure(_tls_wrap.js: 1088: 34)\ n at TLSSocket.emit(events.js: 198: 13)\ n at TLSSocket._finishInit(_tls_wrap.js: 666: 8)\ n code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'`
...
`Client request error: unable to verify the first certificate`

- Since this seems to be a JavaScript error, my first approach was to point `npm` to the same keystore which also `curl` uses and which has no problem with the URL. Via `npm config set cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
- After that didn't work I tried to disable the SSL verification altogether just to see if it works. Via `npm config set strict-ssl false`
- That failed so I read the docs about [certificate validation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/openid-connect/#certificate-validation), tried to set up `pemtrustedcas_filepath` with the keystore above... didn't work.
- Then tried to download the cert and use `pemtrustedcas_content`, but that didn't work either.

Out of options. Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue? if yes, you can add that as an answer to your question.

Comment: @aditya_sharma No, we ended up using an official cert with a hack. But looking back the solution is probably to use the Node binaries inside `/opensearch-dashboards-2.4.0/node/`. Looks like Dashboards uses its own Node version instead of the one installed on the system. No idea how to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `opensearch_security.openid.root_ca: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in opensearch_dashboards.yml worked for me.